# Parsing react props to react component from HTML view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I am working on a project that is mainly made with PHP and HTML, And I want to create a widget with React.js.

To achieve this, What I did was, I created React component and used its react tag on the HTML view like this, Everything works fine except parsing props.

My HTML view:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 prod-schedule" id="ProgressBarWidget">
    <ProgressBars date='foo'></ProgressBars>
</div>
```

Corresponding react component JS:

```
const Element = document.getElementById("ProgressBarWidget");

class ProgressBars extends React.Component{

    render(props){
        return (
            <div>
                <label>Cakes</label>
                <div className="progress">
                    <div className="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40"
                    aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style={{width:60+'%'}}>
                        40% Complete {this.props.date}
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<ProgressBars />, Element);
```

My problem is parsing this 'date' property to react component. It works when I add that prop to render function like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(<ProgressBars date='sample'/>, Element);
```

But I want to parse it from the HTML view.

- I am using react CDN.
- Date is just dummy data I will integrate real values with it later.

Comment: should you not be getting your props from a constructor since it's a class component ?
And did you log the props to be sure it's getting parse?

Comment: I tried getting it from the constructor but it comes as undefined. @Wale

Comment: let me run a sample then, one min

Comment: So let me get you straight, what you are trying to achieve is to render react component  without using `ReactDOM.render`?

Comment: No, I just want to parse props to the component from where it is called. @AlanOmar

Answer (score 0):

`React` renders a react component into some valid DOM element.
What you've done with your PHP (`<ProgressBars date='foo'></ProgressBars>`) is not valid DOM element.

You need to render with your PHP code a placeholder for the widget, usually used with `id` (like you did).
Then render the `React` element into it.

If you want to pass data from PHP to the react component you have several options:

1. If you have few values to pass, you can pass them using `data` attribute

```
// some-file.php
<div
  class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 prod-schedule"
  id="ProgressBarWidget"
  data-prop1="value1"
  data-prop2="value2"></div>
```

```js
const Element = document.getElementById("ProgressBarWidget");
const data = {
  prop1: Element.dataset.props1,
  prop2: Element.dataset.props2,
};

class ProgressBars extends React.Component {
  render(props) {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>Cakes</label>
        <div className="progress">
          <div
            className="progress-bar progress-bar-success"
            role="progressbar"
            aria-valuenow="40"
            aria-valuemin="0"
            aria-valuemax="100"
            style={{ width: 60 + '%' }}>
            40% Complete {this.props.date}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ProgressBars data={data} />, Element);
```

2. If you have large json, generate an inline script tag with id, and parse it's content

```
// some-file.php
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 prod-schedule" id="ProgressBarWidget"></div>
<script type="application/json" id="ProgressBarWidgetData">
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "foo1": "bar2",
  ... // your large data object
}
</script>
```

```js
const Element = document.getElementById("ProgressBarWidget");
const data = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("ProgressBarWidgetData").contentText);

class ProgressBars extends React.Component {
  render(props) {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>Cakes</label>
        <div className="progress">
          <div
            className="progress-bar progress-bar-success"
            role="progressbar"
            aria-valuenow="40"
            aria-valuemin="0"
            aria-valuemax="100"
            style={{ width: 60 + '%' }}>
            40% Complete {this.props.date}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ProgressBars data={data} />, Element);
```

Comment: Yeah, this would work. So there is no way to get data as props in this matter?

Comment: `React` component doesn't get it's props from the DOM, so no :]

Comment: Argh! I need to use a global variable and access it inside the React component then. Thank you.